# Can't Access wamp server (localhost) on my android device again

Tags: android, apache, wamp, wampserver

1
I am developing a responsive website and i want to check it on my android devices (mobile, tablet). I am trying to access my server in the mobile browser's window using my ip (192.168.1.100). I have tried various methods discussed here like access-localhost-from-mobile-phone

I have also edited my apache config file as suggested but nothing working. No matter what i do, i get Forbidden, you don't have permission to access / on this server. I am running apache 2.4

I have also tried

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

then

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require ip 255.255.255 (my subnet)
</Directory>
```

then

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require ip 192.168.1.100(my IPv4)
</Directory>
```

then
    
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    
then

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Nothing works for me...

Comment: Turn off your firewall and anti-virus. Those programs usually blocks wampServer connection, even if you allow it to go through firewall. Also, try running wampServer as Administrator

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: Oh and replace that section of the `httpd.conf` to the way you found it. You should not amend that part of `httpd.conf` as it it the first step in protecting an Apache system from hacking

Comment: I did that. I turned my antivirus and firewall off and I still can't get it to work. I'm using wamp 2.5

Answer (score 2):

For future purposes if anyone finds this thread. This is how to do it for apache 2.4.*

go to your path to root folder of wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra

Open te file : httpd-vhosts.conf

edit this line : Require local

to : **Require all granted**

Now make a hotspot on your phone or tablet. Connect the laptop/pc to ur hotspot and type /ipconfig in cmd on your laptop/pc. Now go to your phone and type in the ipv4 address given in the cmd. Now you can acces your localhost.